# Measure Android Activity Rendering Time

Tags: android, android-activity, rendering

In my Android App, I want to measure the time how long it takes from clicking a button in Activity A to see the full drawn layout of Activity B.

I thought of doing this with Log. While I could print out the start time within the onClick-Method of the Button, I am not sure where to put the Log for the end time.

How can I recognise if Activity B is fully drawn? Is there a method e.g. like onAfterRendering?

Comment: Did you get my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a lool on the [activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html), you can put your code that checks the time when `onResume` is called:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //check the time
}
```